# Optimizing search query for multiple search criteria

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search functionality where I have multiple search criteria like State,District,University,Programme,Level,Courses, Institutes etc. This itself makes 7 search criteria. 
I can search using any one search criteria or all or any combination. By this I have to check for all the possibility of search i.e. 2^7 combination using IF-ELSEIF loop. 
I want to avoid this method of searching since any day if a new criteria comes up that increases the complexity of code by power of 2. Is there any better algorithm which can be useful to tackle this performance issue with my search.

I am implementing the same using PHP-MySQL.

Regards,
Suvojit

Comment: Be clear with your codes...

Comment: yeah I have aready implemented using where clause using diffrent combinations. but that takes 2^7 possible if-else checks and performance issue arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your $sql string dynamically with where clause created using php implode. Case solved